# SpringBoot application Tomcat deployment

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application that I am trying to deploy to Tomcat Server. According to references online, I have added some code in the Application class as follows:

```
public class SkyVetApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
...
   @Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SkyVetApplication.class);
}
...
}
```

In `build.gradle` I have added the following:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
**providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'**
```

After doing a clean build I have copied the war file to Tomcat's `webapps` folder. But the deployment happens twice and ends with an exception as context is already present. What am I missing?

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using spring boot, then a embedded tomcat server herewith. Just package your `war` to `jar` (in `pom.xml` find `<package>jar</package>`) and run your jar using the command `java -jar ABC.jar`.

Comment: I want to deploy on tomcat

Comment: Then why you are using `spring-boot`? Just create a web project, build a war file  and deploy it.

Comment: I don't think there is enough here to reproduce your issue.  The rest of the gradle file (at least dependencies and plugins) would probably help.  It also wouldn't hurt to include the versions you're using of Java, Boot, Tomcat, etc. Portions of the Tomcat config (e.g. `server.xml`, `context.xml`) _might_ be useful.  Of course, a public Git repository containing a MCVE would be even better.

Comment: Have you looked at the tomcat logs? I used to deploy spring boot applications to tomcat a while back, and I don't remember duplicate deployment as a problem (even when the tomcat dependencies were accidentally included). But there are scenarios when tomcat's auto deploy interferes with manually configured contexts (mainly as `<Context ...>` in `server.xml` or with `context.xml` files with wrongly configured `docBase` or `path` attributes).

Comment: Also I second the request for more information.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to deploy on your Tomcat server and Spring boot is deploying on embedded tomcat  too. For standalone tomcat deployment  try using  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You should add a main method.

Check out these examples: https://github.com/Pytry/bootiful-war-deployment

Here's an example from the "hello" module (it's using Lombok annotation processors).

```
package com.example.bootifulwar;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class HelloServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Value("${messageForUser}")
    private String message;

    @Value("${whatDoesTheFoxSay:'No body knows.'}")
    private String whatDoesTheFoxSay;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SpringApplication.run(HelloServletInitializer.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void sayHelloTo(){

        log.info("Hello! " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){

        log.info(
            "\n*********************\n" +
                "What does the fox say?\n" +
                whatDoesTheFoxSay +
                "\n*********************\n");
        return application.sources(HelloServletInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

To take advantage of individualized logging and external "application.properties", assuming you deploy more than one war file to the same Tomcat, you will need to place a custom context.xml for each applications context-path inside of "conf/Catalina/localhost.".

Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="hello.war" path="hello">
  <Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
    <PreResources base="hello\\config"
                  className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                  internalPath="/"
                  webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

I'm not an expert at gradlem but your dependencies look fine.

Hope that helps.